What is the difference between "@ModelAttribute Taco design" and "@ModelAttribute("design") Taco design"?
I am new to spring and recently confused by @ModelAttribute used in method parameter. Sometimes i see a string is passed to it as @ModelAttribute("design") Taco design. Sometimes the brackets are missed as @ModelAttribute Taco design. So What is the difference between them? Can anybody explain it?

Nothing, unless you don't compile with debug info or parameter info in JDK 17 or up. Generally both will do a lookup for a model attribute named design. If you don't mention it explicitly it will be inferred from the parameter name, which if isn't compiled into the class (with debug information or parameter names enabled) will be something like argx where x is the number of the parameter in the method declaration.
